# Setting Up a Python Script on Ubuntu Server

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, ubuntu-server

Hello I just finished my a project this last spring and built a ~1500 line Python/MySQL Raspberry Pi home automation server.  I have a home server built with Ubuntu Server installed and have everything setup on the GUI at the moment for debugging.  I would like to have it setup so that as soon as the the server turns on manually or by wake on LAN that it automatically runs my python script.  The issue I have had with this method is that since there are many threads in the program I cannot use control-c to stop the program and this would prevent me from accessing the GUI for more debugging in the future.  I have had not experience with Ubuntu server and would like to know the options here.
-Thanks

Comment: First, strip the GUI stuff from it and put it in a separate module; you don't want that running on a dedicated server. Second, find a tutorial for writing systemd unit files.

Comment: Looked into the tutorial and looks doable thanks, any explanation for not including the GUI in the server really my project is only going to online for the short term to test than I may use the GUI again to make changes

Comment: Dedicated servers don't have GUIs.